# exitBlockOnFail causes my failing my script with "failed to execute: No attribute named "

Tags: scala, gatling

So I have a scenario that works perfectly, its defined as follows:

```
 val basicLoginScenario = createScenario(Config.testName, feeder.random,

      setSessionParams(PARAM1, Config.param1),
      setSessionParams(PARAM2, Config.param2),
      setSessionParams(PARAM3, Config.param3),
      setSessionParams(PARAM4, Config.param4),
      exec(RestApi.userLogin))
      exec(RestApi.transaction1))
      exec(RestApi.transaction2)))
```

But when I surround it with exitBlockOnFail, I am getting the following error and it seems to happen before any HTTP request is sent or any request/response JSON is being parsed.

```
[GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR io.gatling.http.action.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-5' failed to execute: No attribute named 'cookie' is defined
```

This is the code with exitBlockOnFail:

```
val basicLoginScenario = createScenario(Config.testName, feeder.random,
    exitBlockOnFail{
      setSessionParams(PARAM1, Config.param1)
      setSessionParams(PARAM2, Config.param2)
      setSessionParams(PARAM3, Config.param3)
      setSessionParams(PARAM4, Config.param4)
      exec(RestApi.userLogin))
      exec(RestApi.transaction1))
      exec(RestApi.transaction2))
    })
```

Note that the "cookie" parameter is being fetched from the userLogin transaction and is not used anywhere before it is fetched in this scenario, obviously not in setSessionParam which is:

```
  def setSessionParams(key: String, value: Any) = {
    exec(_.set(key, value))
  }
```

Here is the userLogin transaction:

```
  val userLogin = {
    exec(http("Login")
      .post("/login")
      .body(ElFileBody("json/Login.json")).asJson
      .check(jsonPath("$.result.cookie").saveAs("cookie")))
  }
```

My feeder doesn't have a "cookie" parameter in it and the Login.json doesn't have a "cookie" parameter assigned in it, it only returns it. As I said at the beginning, the scenario works perfectly - the issue only occurs when i surround my transactions with exitBlockOnFail. Any idea what might cause it?

Comment: what's the definition of createScenario? I notice in your original example, you're separating the setSessionParam calls with a ',', but you've dropped that in the exitBlockOnFail version

Comment: With your help on my other questions, I will eventually have to start paying you :) Anyways, here is the definition:  def createScenario(name: String, feed: FeederBuilder, chains: ChainBuilder*): ScenarioBuilder = {
    scenario(name).feed(feed).forever() {
      exec(chains)
    }
  } I am not entirely sure why ',' are needed for setSessionParam but my IDE doesn't like it if I remove it. Unfortunately I had to jump dive into scala and gatling without enough time to learn it properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial version works because 'exec' can take a varargs of execs whereas 'exitBlockOnFail' takes a chain. So when you supply several execs to 'exitBlockOnFail', only the last action is being executed.

so you can either wrap all the statements in an 'exec'

```
exitBlockOnFail{
  exec(
    setSessionParams(PARAM1, Config.param1),
    ...
    exec(RestApi.transaction2)
  )
}
```

or chain them

```
exitBlockOnFail{
  setSessionParams(PARAM1, Config.param1)
  .setSessionParams(PARAM1, Config.param1)
  .setSessionParams(PARAM2, Config.param2)
  .setSessionParams(PARAM3, Config.param3)
  .setSessionParams(PARAM4, Config.param4)
  .exec(RestApi.userLogin)
  .exec(RestApi.transaction1)
  .exec(RestApi.transaction2)
}
```